# ask about database erd admin and client login

Tags: mysql, database, web

I want to ask, if I have

1. Client (client name, company name, telephone number)
2. Admin (admin name, telephone number, handphone number)

If I want to make erd, how to make table login for this question...
If client login, client will get client User interface
Then if admin login will get admin User interface

I use `connoly` and `begg base knowledge`...

Please help me to make ERD...

I think to make like this

```
usergroup{group_id,group_name}
client{client_id,client_name,company_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

After successful login redirect the user to respective page 
eg-

```
if ($_session['client'])
redirect to home page of client.
else if ($_session['webadmin'])
redirect to admin dashboard
```

you can use login check appropriately via post method .